# Code not running fully in VsCode but working in online compilers

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

This is the code i am talking about. It checks if a matrix is sparse or not . If it is then it changes it to sparse form and transposes it. When I run it with Vscode it runs and displays till it is sparse matrix but doesn't show its sparse form and transpose form but on online compiler it runs successfully till the end.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int checksparse();
int changematrix();

int main()
{
    int a[100][100];
    int i, j, r, c;
    printf("Enter number of rows and columns in the matrix\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &r, &c);
    printf("\nEnter the elements in the matrix");
    for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            printf("\na[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    int check = checksparse(a, r, c);
    if (check == 1)
    {
        printf("\nIts a sparse matrix\n");
        changematrix(a, r, c);
    }
    else if (check == 0)
    {
        printf("\nIts not a sparse matrix");
    }
    return 0;
}
int checksparse(int array[100][100], int r, int c)
{
    int counter = 0, flag = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            if (array[i][j] == 0)
                counter++;
        }
    }
    if (counter > ((r * c) / 2))
    {
        return flag;
    }
    else
    {
        flag = 0;
        return flag;
    }
}
int changematrix(int array[100][100], int r, int c)
{
    int b[100][100], temp, counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            if (array[i][j] != 0)
            {
                b[temp][0] = i;
                b[temp][1] = j;
                b[temp][2] = array[i][j];
                temp++;
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\nSparse Matrix : \n");

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", b[i][j]);
            printf("\t");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\nTranspose of Sparse Matrix : \n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < counter; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", b[j][i]);
            printf("\t");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: one problem I see, `temp` in `changematrix` is uninitialized, so `b[temp]` invokes undefined behavior

Comment: Thank you so much. It solved the problem. But i dont know why then it worked in online compilers

Comment: [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) is just that, _undefined_. Trying to understand exactly why it performed in a particular way is a fruitless effort. As you've seen, behavior can change across systems, also with different compilers, compiler flags, even different iterations of running your code. [This](https://www.wikiod.com/w/C_Undefined_behavior) is a nice list (but probably not comprehensive) of ways you can invoke undefined behavior in C. Next time you see symptoms like this, examine your code for these problems.